# How to avoid Yii from Capitalize our labels?

Tags: yii

If we call this:

```
<?php echo $form->label($model,'Hello my friend'); ?>
```

We get output it on the viewport the following:

> "Hello My Friend"

On the CSS I have **nothing** that says **capitalize**, **anywhere**.

How can we change this behavior ?

I've tried to edit the CSS and make:

```
label {
text-transform: none !important;
}
```

No luck.

How can we have

> Hello my friend

printed exactly as we write it ?

Comment: the second parameter to `label()` is supposed to an attribute name, is your attribute's name `Hello my friend`?

Comment: @bool.dev - yes, I got that. (see my answer above). If you desire please answer and I will delete mine and make yours as an answer. :)

Comment: no its ok! you got your own answer, so that's good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of doing like this on the view file:

```
<?php echo $form->label($model, 'Hello my friend'); ?>
```

We have change it to:

```
<?php echo $form->label($model, 'hello_friend'); ?>
```

where hello_friend is defined on the respective model method attributeLabels(), like this:

```
'hello_friend' => 'Hello my friend')
```

So, as bool.dev properly says, we have to place the attribute name AND NOT a random string.